# How to choose a quality profile when filtering issues of a project?

Tags: sonarqube

I once had an extra filter for all rules/problems, whose issues had been fixed up completely in the project, so I would easily see new ones regarding these rules (issue count of that filter rises from 0 to ...).

With version 6.3.1 filters are not supported anymore, so I created a quality profile including the same rules.

My problem is that it's only possible to activate 1 single quality profile for the project, so I can't filter these rules anymore. I also tried to use a parent quality profile, without success. The solved issues of the rules are completely in the 'normal' quality profile, if that's of importance.

How can I configure SonarQube, so that the system analyses 2 quality profiles on the same project?

I read of a work around that just creates a second branch of the project to analyse that one, but I am seeking out for a cleaner solution.

Example:

Quality Profile 'fixed rules':

- count 0: use diamond operator
- count 0: no stupid equality checks

Quality Profile 'all activated rules':

- count 0: use diamond operator
- count 0: no stupid equality checks
- count 100: variable does not match pattern xyz
- count 500: switch case without default
- ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to add another quality profile. Actually, the project only needs to be analyzed once.

Why don't you just set the tag 'fixed' to all your solved rules? Then you can easily filter the issues with that tag and see the results.